# "Failed to load the torrent...." when I try to open pdf files on another partition

Tags: partitioning, pdf, bittorrent

I have qBittorent installed on my system Ubuntu 14.04. When going to my DATA partition which is NTFS. When trying to open the pdf I get this:

```
Failed to load the torrent: /media/justin/DATA/Documents/eBooks/calculus/
James Stewart-Calculus, 7th Edition  -Cengage Learning (2011).pdf.
Error: metadata too large
```

I don't know what this means and it does not let me open the pdf files even if I copy them to my Home folder. What should I do to open my pdf files?

Comment: A pdf file is not a torrent file. Usually torrent files have the extension `.torrent`. Please try to open your pdf file with evince, `evince "/path/filename.pdf"` or open evince and use its own file browser to find the file.

Comment: Yes that way it works as expected. Should I just reassign the file association?

Comment: That is a good idea :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason qBittorent became the default program to open pdf files. Just reassign the file association with evince.

In order to do this:

1. RIght click file then select properties
2. Choose "open with" tab For
       default application
3. Select document viewer and click "set as default"

Answer (score -1):

Why are you trying to open pdf file in qBittorent? As I know qBittorent is not a pdf reader. I suggest you to use pdf reader as Foxit Reader to open pdf files or the default one which is already installed in your Linux System.